# running sail artisan migrate gives an error

Tags: php, laravel

hello everyone so I am new to Laravel I've started learning Laravel 7 then I upgraded from Laravel 7 to Laravel 8 and I am kind of lost
when ever I try to run a migration like this

```
sail artisan migrate
```

I get an error

> sail : The term 'sail' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
> operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
> path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1

- sail artisan migrate
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sail:String) [], CommandNotFoundException      
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

so instead I have tried to run

`php artisan migrate`

but I also got an error

> PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=store", "sail", "password", [])

so I am stuck at this point, any help would be really appreciated

I did read throw Laravel's Documentation but I didn't find a solution I've already did the steps to add sail to an existing project but I guess it didn't work for some reason

**thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question**

Comment: try this step-by-step tutorial https://youtu.be/rr6AngDpgnM  ; 
Text version also available in the youtube description...

Answer (score 0):

Morning,

I'm also learning Laravel through punches so I'll try my best here.

To start using sail on my project I needed some extras commands (sorry I don't know if you already used):

`composer require laravel/sail --dev`

`php artisan sail:install`

If you are using Windows:

- Did you try to run the command from WSL?
- Is docker desktop Up and working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for your answer! Follow-up questions are best posted as a comment to the original question.